# Cython: Invalid index type 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, python-3.x, int, cython

I am wondering why cython is complaining about using `int` as indices in arrays.

I have a really long function, but there is an array cython is complaining about, it is implemented like so:

```
cdef double F(double[:,:] arguments):
    cdef double H[2][3][3]
    H[0][0][:] = [0, 0, 0]; H[0][1][:] = [0, 0, 0]; H[0][2][:] = [0, 0, 0]
    H[1][0][:] = [0, 0, 0]; H[1][1][:] = [0, 0, 0]; H[1][2][:] = [0, 0, 0]
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef int j = 0

    # ...

    # the following line causes the error

    H[<int>1,i,j] = 42

    # ...
```

I get the error `Invalid index type '(int, int, int)'`

Is it true that I cannot use `int` as index? What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one cannot access the array in this way

```
H[<int>1,i,j] = 42
```

Writing

```
H[<int>1][i][j] = 42
```

solves the problem.